# Understanding the arguments to an Apache module directory config merge function

Tags: c, apache, apache2

I am writing an Apache module and I have run into some confusion regarding the behavior of the directory configuration merge function.

In the source for [mod_example](http://apache.wirebrain.de/lxr/source/modules/experimental/mod_example.c), the parameters are labelled like this:

```
static void *x_merge_dir_config(apr_pool_t *p, void *parent_conf, void *newloc_conf);
```

But given directives like this:

```
<Location /path/>
  MyOption value-from-path
</Location>

<Location />
  MyOption value-from-root
</Location>
```

When this function is called as a result of an access to http://localhost/path/, the function is called with parent_conf coming from `/path/` and newloc_conf coming from `/`, which is exactly the opposite of what I would expect based on the names of these parameters.  I would describe "/" as the parent and "/blog/" as the child/subordinate/most specific path.

I'm trying to figure out what the real story is here.  Is Apache using the word "parent" differently than I do?  Has mod_example erroneously misnamed these parameters?  Am I simply confused?

Comment: Hello, Voting to Close person: it would help me if you would leave a comment when leaving your vote, since from my perspective this is absolutely a software development question.  I mean, it's a question about writing against a C API for a major piece of software; that does seem on target.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the "parent"/"new" args have more to do with the order in which Apache applies configuration directives than the pathnames associated with those directives. As you know it starts with the per-server, then vhost, then `Location` sections, etc., with later directives in this list overriding earlier ones. And the job of the merge callback is to compute the result of overriding the stuff in "parent" with the stuff in "newloc".

If multiple Location sections match a request, [they are applied in the order they appear in the config file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#mergin). Therefore, when `MyOption value-from-root` is merged in, it is the "new" piece of configuration— it's being applied after `value-from-path`— so it is in the "newloc" arg, and the configuration computed up to that point, including `value-from-path`, is in "parent".

(As an aside, unless your module has an unusual merge behavior, this means you probably want to swap the order of the two Location sections. The second one, for root, will *always* apply, and will presumably prevent the first one from ever having a visible effect.)

Comment: Wow, I'd given up on ever getting a response here.  Thanks for your thoughts; I'll try some experiments this evening and see how it looks.